# How can I directly execute SQL queries in linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

In C# with VS 2008,I have a query ,In this query i join more than one tables,so i don't know the type , I want to know how to directly run a sql query in linq .

```
IEnumerable<Type> results = db.ExecuteQuery<TYpe>("sql query")
```

My above query works fine but I want to avoid  type, I want to write

```
var results = db.ExecuteQuery("sql query");
```

Is there any way to write it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is it supposed for linq2sql to detect what class it needs to map the results? Btw, you're still able to use `var` in the first sample, aren't you?

Comment: Is it possible to use a stored procedure? The designer will generate a class for each stored procedures return type if so.

Comment: Give some sample queries. What are you trying to accomplish? Are the return types the same, but just from different tables?

Comment: **You can't run SQL in LINQ.** LINQ is a C# language concept. It doesn't run SQL. That said, many ORMs offer options to run raw SQL. How to do that generally isn't hard to find in their documentation.

Answer (score 12):

```
    var result = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<JobsDto>
                 ("Select JobID,JobName From jobs");
```

but make sure `JobsDto` has two properties `JobID` and `JobName` and there types the same type as the table columns

PS. DTO stand for Data Transfer Object

Comment: **Note:** If you just need a quick test, you can also make the properties dynamic like so: `public class JobsDto { public dynamic JobsID; public dynamic JobName; }`, and use a tool like [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to dump the result. Assign them the default value `null` to avoid warnings and use result type `IEnumerable<JobsDto>`.

Comment: In my case, I needed to select aggregated values. Create a new class model "dto", as suggested. But had to alter a bit. dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<AggregatedValuesDto>("SQL statement").SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify the type to map to from the query results. You can use a `System.Type` object instead of statically specifying it as a generic type parameter:

```
var results = db.ExecuteQuery(typeof(Customer), "sql query ");
```

If you just want a plain ADO.NET DataReader you could use the `DataContext.Connection` property:

```
using (var cmd = db.Connection.CreateCommand()) 
{ 
  cmd.CommandText = "sql query ";
  var results = cmd.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: Correct, but the question was about Linq. You cannot use the results directly in Linq.

Comment: @Matt: The question was about the LINQ-to-SQL API, not the language query feature.

Comment: Ok, I agree. However, I prefer the Generic notation.